# Visual studio signing app with cordova 5.1.1

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, sign

Im developing an app with Cordova 5.1.1 in visual studio 2015, I can debug it and release it without sign, when I try to add the code for sign it I have a problem.
This is the code for 5.1.1 for sign app (modify build.json):

```
 {
 "android": {
    "release": {
        "keystore": "example.keystore",
        "storePassword": "example",
        "alias": "example",
        "password" : "example",
        "keystoreType": ""
         }
    }
}
```

and this is the error

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\example\example\platforms\android\..\..\example.keystore
```

the keystore is in the folder platform\android but i don't understand why there are \..\..\ I never add this

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path C:\Users\Simone\Desktop\example\example\platforms\android....\example.keystore
is misleading.

TO solve this issue just copy the keystore file to the project root.